# Loop structs and check nested to find matching value

Tags: go, struct, interface

I have a Go struct like so:

```
type AuditStruct struct {
 UsesResponsiveImages struct {
        ID               string
        Details          struct {
            Type     string
        }
 }
 UsesWebpImages struct {
        ID               string
        Details          struct {
            Type     string
        }
 }
 FontDisplay struct {
        ID               string
        // NO Details
 }
 .. etc etc
}
```

I want to iterate over each Audit sub-struct and check if its Details.Type is equal to "blah".

Intended outcome is to return the data with matching details.type to a result. Currently using reflect but can't work it out.

```
v := reflect.ValueOf(audits)

values := make([]interface{}, v.NumField())

 for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
   vDetails := v.Field(i).FieldByName("Details")
   // Cannot get type from vDetails.

   // Tried using values and interface but unsure how to access "type" sub value from values[i]
   values[i] = v.Field(i).Interface()
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. Drill into the Types field using FieldByName:

```
for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
    vDetails := v.Field(i).FieldByName("Details")
    if !vDetails.IsValid() {
        continue
    }
    vType := vDetails.FieldByName("Type")
    if !vType.IsValid() {
        continue
    }
    values[i] = vType.Interface()
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/7oGJ58kBFFd).